# Get the path to the Room & Resources database in IBM Domino?

Tags: resources, calendar, lotus-domino

I need to programmatically find the path to the Room & Resources database, preferably accessible thru a HTTP request. Just placing a HTTP request and getting the path/filename returned somewhere in the response would be sufficient.

And/Or are there any assumptions that can be made in regards to the file/path-name of Rooms & Resources? So, at the very least, I can provide an educated guest to the end user.

Since the room & resource database may be clustered - a way to determine this would also be appreciated and preferably thru a HTTP request.

NO changes can be made to the environment to get this information - this means no programming in the users mailfile or any other design changes.

The question is in regard to IBM Domino 8.5+

/J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the information "somewhere in the response" is quite easy: Just use the hidden ($Users)- View to get that information: 
`http://servername/names.nsf/($Users)/Resource%2FOrga?OpenDocument`

As you see, you have to encode the slashes in the resource name with %2F

The respons will be a website, that contains Server AND FilePath in two fields:

`<input name="MailServer" type="hidden" value="YourServer/Org">`
`<input name="MailFile" type="hidden" value="pathtoresourcedatabase.nsf">`

In that document there is only the "main" server. Information about clustering would have to be obtained by looking up the MailServer- Value (in a canonicalized form) in the view ($Servers):

`http://servername/names.nsf/($Servers)/CN=YourServer%2FO=Org?OpenDocument`

In the result there will be a field called ClusterName:

`<input name="ClusterName" type="hidden" value="YourClusterName">`

And with that information you could lookup the clustermembers using the view called ($Clusters), but there you have to parse the information, as this is not a single document... Just check the output of:

`http://servername/names.nsf/($Clusters)?OpenView`

If you need to get a "better parseable" result, then use `ReadViewEntries` instead of OpenView, then the result is XML (or json, if you add another parameter &outputformat=JSON)

Answer (score 0):

Theres a view for rooms and resources in the names.nsf. You can probably query this view with an http request and parse the result, to find out the path to the resource databases.

BTW. it is possible to have multiple resource database.